# How do I rename a file with custom pattern in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am splitting a large file and need to generate filenames like 
file.x.y.txt

x is the file split number and y is the total number of splits.

The files are already generated as file.x.txt through some complicated process.

I have this so far:

```
from("file://out?include=*.txt&amp;move=${file:name}.<how to set this>.txt")
```

I could not figure out how to pass this to the consumer the y number.

Comment: You can use a java bean to compute the file name, there is a little example in the camel file documentation

Comment: We need a lot more detail than this to help. Where is the split you mention? Before or after the reading the file?

Comment: Claus's comment helped.  The main missing piece of information was how to save state between routes and do some arbitrary processing. The exchange to save state presumably does not work all the time. So the best solution and accepted pattern seems to be with a singleton bean. It still feels a little wrong to me but its working fine.